# How to log in to WIndows after disabling all services?

Tags: windows-10, boot, services, msconfig

I disabled all services and startup applications and now the computer won't let me log in. It will get me to the initial startup screen, but it won't connect to the Internet. Then when I click or press a key to log in, the password box never appears.

How to go back to normal boot? Shift+Restart or F8 to get into safe mode doesn't work. Restoring to a system restore point resulted in an error. Even Resetting Windows didn't work.

Comment: @Ramhound how should I fail it? Just hard power off when it starts to boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to access safe mode boot without having to logon:

1. Interrupt Windows booting process four times
2. Open Command Prompt from an installation disk, enter **`bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal`**, then restart

After that, you can open `msconfig` and undo what you've done.

Source: [7 ways to boot into Safe Mode in Windows 10](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10)

Comment: Not the best way but I've done this few times myself.

Answer (score -1):

Very good content and reconfiguration option, had the same problem and worked.

Complete Material.

Type the following command to exit safe mode:
bcdedit / deletevalue {default} safe boot and press Enter.

Command prompt with the Exit Safe Mode command

Close the Command Prompt window by clicking the X in the upper right corner of the Command Prompt window.

The Choose an option screen appears. Select Continue.
The computer starts normally.